# Integral $\frac{x^{1/4} }{ x^{1/2}-1}$ dx

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Tried multiplying and dividing my $x^4$ and also tried substitutions for $x^{1/2}$ , $x^{1/4}$ but reaching nowhere , just give me the clue on how to start .

Comment: Hint: Things will look more familiar  if you let $x=u^4$.

Comment: Tried that way too ;(

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+x%5E%281%2F4%29+%2F%28+x%5E%281%2F2%29-1%29+dx

Comment: @MathBot I think the idea is trying to compute that integral manually. We can of course check with Wolfram to see if we did it right

Comment: @SujithZis Follow Andre's suggestion...

Comment: you should learn some basic latex. this is your 6th post and you are no able to write powers of x in latex.

Comment: @miracle173 im really sorry , i will learn asap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A start:** Let $x=u^4$. Then we end up wanting to integrate $\frac{4u^4}{u^2-1}$. Note this is $\frac{4(u^4-1)}{u^2-1}+\frac{4}{u^2-1}$. Continue.

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$and then $dx = 4u^3\,du$, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Lol i had forgot to substitute for dx :P thanks soo much